# Bash startup script in Windows

Tags: windows, bash

I am using the Bash shell with Git in Windows.  I have a number of aliases I wish to setup when I open the shell.  Is there a configuration file that is invoked for each Bash instance that is brought up?

Comment: Try editing `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks @Blender, that was the answer.  Here is what I did...

Start bash (Git bash)

```
cd
touch .bashrc
notepad .bashrc
source .bashrc # To make changes available without restart
```

entered aliases...save
close bash
start bash
aliases are now available!